# JSTL: Set and Compare JSTL variable

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I have a list of ADs and I want to group them by `StartOn (timestamp)`. The list is sorted by StartOn already. So I loop through the list, `if startOnCur != ad.StartOn`, I print the timestamp and assign StartOn to `startOnCur (temp var)`.

The problem is that I am not able to assign `ad.StartOn` to `ad.StartOn`. What am I missing? Thanks!

```
<c:set var="startOnCur" value=""/>
<c:forEach items="${ads}" var="ad" >            
  <c:if test="${startOnCur != ad.startOn}">
  <legend><fmt:formatDate pattern="EEE. MMM. d" value="${ad.startOn}" /></legend>
  <c:set var="startOnCur" value="${ad.startOn}" scope="session"/>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i removed scope="session", it's working now.